# I have issues when I run laravel project from github

Tags: php, laravel

i cloned laravel project from GitHub but when i try to open it by wiring composer install it appeared

```
No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires fzaninotto/faker ^1.7 -> satisfiable by fzaninotto/faker[v1.7.0, ..., v1.9.2].
    - fzaninotto/faker[v1.7.0, ..., v1.9.2] require php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - phpunit/phpunit[5.7.0, ..., 5.7.27] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.7.0, ..., 5.7.27].
```

Comment: Duplicate. Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70914060/984422

Comment: please composer update

Answer (score 0):

try run composer update if not working you need to upgrade composer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: composer update instead of composer install